# Microsoft Graph API Python SDK "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

i'm trying to get user data from AAD using Microsoft Graph API Python SDK.
App registration that i have in company tenant has the followiing API permissions:
[image]

I'm using the following piece of code to get user's details from AAD:

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="appClientId",
    secret="appClientSecret",
    resource="https://graph.windows.net",
    tenant = 'companyTenant'
)

tenant_id = 'companyTenantId'

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)

user = graphrbac_client.users.get("myUserObjectId")
```

And get "azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error_py3.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

I'm using Python 3.10.5 and my app service should be able to get data of any user from AAD.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it came out that the issue was that i was using wrong SDK, the one that i've used was working with the AAD graph but i need Microsoft.Graph (if the permission that i've granted to the app registration would be of the AAD Graph type - then it would work, but since AAD Graph cannot be assigned anymore to the app registration since it is deprecated i've assigned Microsoft.Graph permission).
So the fix was to use another SDK from MS (that is currenty in preview) and it worked for me, here is the code:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id='tenantId',client_secret='appRegClientId',client_id='appRegClientSecret')
client = GraphClient(credential=credential)

result = client.get('/users')                   # gets all users
# result = client.get('/users/userObjectId')    # gets a certain user by it's objectId
# result = client.get('/users/email')           # gets a certain user by it's email address

print(result.json())
```

Comment: The code snippet above will return you only part of the user's properties, in order to fetch all of them you have to specify api_version for client properties: 
client = GraphClient(credential=credential, api_version='beta')
And in case you want to get a certain property you can also query it by name like: 
result = client.get('/users/{UPN or ID}}?$select=userPrincipalName,onPremisesSamAccountName')

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the resource are trying to reach out is incorrect , https://graph.windows.net is used when you want to connect to AAD graph , please check the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview.

Could you please try by using the resource = graph.microsoft.com .

graph.microsoft.com is correct endpoint for graph .
please see the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer, however when i adjust the resource as you've mentioned i'm getting another error: "GraphErrorException: Access Token missing or malformed."

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and granted **`API permissions`** like below:

[image]

When I ran the same code as you, I got **same error** as below:

```py
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="appClientId",
    secret="appClientSecret",
    resource="https://graph.windows.net",
    tenant = 'companyTenantId'
)

tenant_id = 'companyTenantId'

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)

user = graphrbac_client.users.get("myUserObjectId")
```

**Response:**

[image]

I agree with ***Vicky kumar*** that **graph.windows.net** is deprecated and you need to change/migrate to ***https://graph.microsoft.com***.

But the **libraries** that you are using won't support this **resource** that results `error` as below:

[image]

Your current library **`azure.graphrbac`** only supports resource as **graph.windows.net** that needs **AAD graph** permissions:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you can make use of below **code** by installing **`urllib3`** library beforehand:

```py
import  urllib3
uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
payload= {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com',
'client_id': '3de439c4-570d-4534-bxxb-e3axxx5d', #Your AppID
'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
'client_secret': 'T2Y8Q~wYQxxxxxxxxxxOODUtFxajo', #Your client secret
'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
 }

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('POST', uri, payload)
my_dict = eval(response.data)
token = f"{my_dict['token_type']}  {my_dict['access_token']}"
#print(token)

uri5 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myUserID'
payload5 = {'Authorization':token,'Host':'graph.microsoft.com','ConsistencyLevel':'eventual'}
https = urllib3.PoolManager()
response5 = http.request('GET', uri5, headers=payload5)
print(response5.data)
```

When I ran the above code, I got the **user details** successfully as below:

[image]

Comment: ah, seems like we were typing an answer simultaneously. I didn't try your approach and stayed with my answer's suggestion to use: msgraph.core and azure.identity. But thanks for your help anyway!